# Ms Access and SQL: how to identify where error occurs

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form in MS Access where a lot of queries are running to calculate all kinds of numbers using user input and using other queries ouput. All of a sudden I get the error below:

[image]

Error text is:

> **The record source ' ' specified on this form or report does not exist.**
>   The name of the recordsource may misspelled, the recordsource was deleted or renamed, or the recordsource exists in a different database.
>   In the Form or Report's design view or layout view, display the property sheet by clicking the properties button, and then set the recordsource property to an existing table or query.

I don't remember exactly what I added/removed to have caused this and I can't find where the error occurs. How can I, I guess, debug my Access Form while it's running queries?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your image as it is blocked at work.

The only one way to debug the application when errors occurs is to break the execution using the keyboard combination :

```
CTRL + Pause/Break
```

Do it when the error message appears

This obviously doesnt work if the application is compiled in a mde/accde

---

When the CTRL-Break doesnt work, you have to add a break point in your code.

Bring the VBA window using

```
ALT + F11
```

Open the code of your form, go in the procedure that triggers the queries, select a line of code at the beginning and add a breakpoint using `F9`

Then run the form, it will stop the execution on the breakpoint and show you the VBA window, continue to execute the code **step-by-step** using `F8` until the error occurs

Comment: That just closes the error message and that's it. I still can't see at what query it occurs. (I added error text for you)

Comment: @Jolien.A I assume your application is not compiled. Anyway that happens sometimes (Unfortunately MS Access isnt always an exact science) I have edited my answer and added  a workaround

Comment: The error message basicaly tells you that your form's recordsource is empty. You can also search in your form's code for the string "recordsource" to spot all the lines where you change it.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you change the name of a table in ms access for that has drop down list, go to the design view --> property Sheet--> Row Source and change the names to the corresponding names for the drop down selection for combo selection